# CFScript's writeDump Doesn't Always Work | cfdump -vs- writeDump

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-10, cfml

On ACF 10, I have a function with the following signature...

```
<cffunction name="...">
    <cfargument ...>
    <cfdump var="#arguments#" output="#expandPath('/files/logs/debug.txt')#">
    <cfscript>
          writeDump(var="#arguments#", output="#expandPath('/files/logs/debug.txt')#");
    </cfscript>
</cffunction>
```

The first tag-based dump works, but the second script-based dump does not. I've had this problem before and I've definitely gotten the tag based dump to work before. It seems random. Sometimes it works, sometimes it doesn't. Once it starts working, it continues... but when it doesn't I can't figure out why.

On the script based variant, I've also tried...

1. WriteDump(...)
2. removing the comma separating the two attributes (an other working example is written this way oddly enough)
3. removing the trailing semi-colon which apparently isn't always necessary per this... [Why writedump function doesn't require semicolon in cfscript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6606208/why-writedump-function-doesnt-require-semicolon-in-cfscript)

Anyone else having this problem and or know what the solution could be?

PS. Anywhere there's a "..." above, it's just to note that that bit is unimportant

Comment: what exactly happens when it... "doesn't work"? are you catching the error?

Comment: Nothing. And I mean absolutely nothing. I get zero output.

Comment: Hmmm. I wonder what happens if you swap the order. Also this sounds like a thing to put into: https://bugbase.adobe.com/

Comment: (Edit) @ChrisGeirman - No output where - on screen, in the file or both? If you mean on screen, that could definitely happen if an [Error is occurring](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14237283/coldfusion-not-catching-noclassdeffounderror/14243560#14243560) (this is different than an exception).  Also, not sure if you saw the question: are you trapping exceptions anywhere - OnError, etcetera?

Comment: Thanks guys. This dump pipes the output to a file rather than show it on screen. So the only place I'd expect to see the dump is in the file. It could definitely be a bug, but sometimes I can get it working in cfscript and sometimes not. And I can't seem to figure out what rhyme or reason causes it. In this particular function, there's no error trapping, try catches, or anything of the sort. I am using the cfwheels framework, so there is higher level error catching at the application level, but that doesn't seem to be tripping either as far as I can tell.

Comment: Just to clarify, the *only* thing going wrong is that WriteDump does NOT write the output to the file. Any code invoked after the function works as expected and there are no errors in any of the application or CF log files, correct?

Comment: Correct, though I should verify the logs

Comment: With the code that's posted, how can one tell which one worked and which one did not?

Comment: If you remove the `output` attribute, and put an `abort` after the second dump, what do you see on the screen?

Comment: That would work. The problem only presents when outputting to a file, which is necessary since this procedure is being called remotely via http, inside a tread. So removing the output isn't an option for me in this case

Comment: It was simply a troubleshooting step to make sure that both `dump`s were working as expected. Dumb, question, but why do you need 2 dumps in this function? I use `writeDump()` quite a bit in my code and I have never seen an issue where it "didn't work"

Comment: I don't actually need two dumps. I was just troubleshooting. My script based version wasn't working, so I added the tag based one, which worked immediately. In fact, tag based dumps that output to a file are very reliable. I've noticed that script based dumps that output to a file are far less reliable, where as script based dumps to the screen are bulletproof. Do you output to file often?

Comment: For troubleshooting? Just about every day. Never had a problem.

Comment: Interesting. Which version of ColdFusion do you use? Maybe this is a ACF10 thing

Answer (score 0):

Try to restart your application

```
reloadApplicationOnEveryRequest = true,
reloadFactoryOnEveryRequest = true
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).